# Foreach loop not

Tags: php, loops, foreach

```
$inputarray=array("username", "password");  

foreach($inputarray as $inputkey);
  if(isset($_POST[$inputkey]) && !empty($_POST[$inputkey]))
  {
    $inputname=$inputkey;
    $inputresult=$_POST[$inputkey];
    $$inputname=$inputresult;
  }
  else
  {
    die("You have to fill both fields.");
  }
```

`$username` isn't being defined, only `$password`. Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Why you need `foreach` at first place?

Comment: I don't see you using variables username or password anywhere in your code.  I only see static strings "username" and "password".

Comment: $inputname is = username, password, $$inputname is $username and $password

Comment: @Lochemage, The `$$` signifies ["variable variables"](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: @Lochemage Note the $$ in front of the second inputname

Comment: @user2635236 am sorry to say this but your code doesn't make any sense, I would suggest you to learn some more php and re code...

Comment: Why do you check for `isset` **and** `empty`? `empty` should check all the things that `isset` does, except it returns `false` if the value is `false`, `0`, an empty string and [other things](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) (whereas `isset` only checks if it exists and it isn't `null`).

Comment: @Mr.Alien My code doesn't make any sense? It works fine now after I fixed a typo

Comment: variable variables? Run... run in the opposite direction. Now. while you can. @Mr.Alien OP is trying to recreate register_globals. That should tell you pretty much everything you need to know...

Comment: @user2635236 Still it doesn't, I don't understand why you are using a loop there

Comment: @MarcB still, his code seems cryptic to me ;)

Comment: @MarcB That's too harsh of a suggestion.  While I agree that variable variables are not appropriate for this use case, he is using a whitelist as opposed to the wildcard overwrite approach of register_globals.  In a non-login page, with lots of inputs to handle, it might actually be a workable approach, at least having a whitelist array and filtering the $_REQUEST array to match the whitelisted names.  Register_globals it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a typo:

`foreach($inputarray as $inputkey);`

You included a semicolon at the end of that line, so the foreach statement runs, then ends, and then the if clause executes on the last value that the foreach statement left in `$inputkey`.

Try:

```
foreach($inputarray as $inputkey)
{
  if(isset($_POST[$inputkey]) && !empty($_POST[$inputkey]))
  {
    $inputname=$inputkey;
    $inputresult=$_POST[$inputkey];
    $$inputname=$inputresult;
  }
  else
  {
    die("You have to fill both fields.");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Error is probably due to the `;` at the end the foreach line. This will cause the foreach line to run leaving to completion, but not run any other statements as there is no enclosure that follows it. Once completed the value of $inputkey will be `"password"` which is why you are only getting data from `"password"`

Try:

```
$inputarray=array("username", "password");  

foreach($inputarray as $inputkey) {
   if(isset($_POST[$inputkey]) && !empty($_POST[$inputkey])) {
      $inputname=$inputkey;
      $inputresult=$_POST[$inputkey];
      $$inputname=$inputresult;
  } else {
     die("You have to fill both fields.");
  }
} //endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Variable variables are a code smell that you're making things hard on yourself.  Instead of doing that, at this stage, and for the specific purposes of a login page, I would make life as simple, readable, and uncomplicated as you can.

Just do this:

```
$username = @$_POST['username']; // Just about the only place where using @ is ok.
$password = @$_POST['password'];
if(!trim($username) || !trim($password)){
    die("You have to fill both fields.");
}
```

A login form is not a place to innovate or make your code complicated.  For a little added abstraction, you could put that information into a simple login validation function so that you can modify the criteria down the line (e.g. username must be longer than 1 character, or whatever).

But from looking at your code, you're making a CLASSIC MISTAKE:

**DO NOT ROLL YOUR OWN LOGIN SYSTEM THE FIRST TIME AROUND**.

Reuse an expert's login code and learn from that.  Write other things in custom php, but borrow someone else's time tested login code for database parameterization, error checking, and abstraction.  Writing your own login system is playing with fire.

Comment: im using it for forms that have 15 input fields

Comment: @user2635236 That doesn't surprise me.  I've been there.  But a login form is not like any other form.  It should be treated with the utmost care and specificity.  In your case, you're making the code that will determine the security of your app unreadably complicated and harder-than-necessary to debug.  Use a whitelisted loop system with your standard input forms, use a tried-and-true third-party login system for your login system.

Comment: ok thx. but can you tell me why my method is so bad? i use input validation before anything important happens

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're assigning the string name `$inputkey` to the value. Also you were creating dynamic variables that you might never have found in your code.

```
$inputarray=array("username", "password");  

foreach($inputarray as $inputkey=>$inputvalue);
  if(isset($_POST[$inputkey]) && !empty($_POST[$inputkey]))
  {
    $inputname=$inputkey;
    $inputresult=$_POST[$inputkey];
    $inputname=$inputresult;
  }
  else
  {
    die("You have to fill both fields.");
  }
```

Comment: I think that was intentional...